# SQL Server 2016: Granting security to do everything but read / write data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, windows-server

We have an offshore support team coming online to support our servers as DBAs for 24x7 support.  However, there are several instances that have a limitation due to contracts that limit offshore access to our data.

What security needs to be added to give them effective control over the servers as DBAs, but limits them to not being able to read/write data?

The instances are in mixed mode, but it would most likely be applied through a AD users group.  SQL Server 2016 and Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. Everything includes granting access, which means they can change whatever access you give them.

There are some encryption methods that can be used so DBA's can have full access but not have readable access to the data. I believe [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017) is one option, but I am not an expert on it.

Make a list of "everything" you want the DBA's to do, then look at the rights required to do that. IMHO, a DBA who does not have sysadmin, is not a DBA.

Comment: Le's assume they do not have security rights.  If that is the case, then is it possible.

Comment: What would a DBA without security-rights do?

Comment: I think it's about backing up? i.e. take copies without being able to read them.

Comment: @Vérace it is simple enough to set up jobs to take backups, you don't need to hire anyone to do that.

Comment: It would be checking jobs, slowness, blocking and general overhead.

Comment: @JamesJenkins True for the backup itself - but what about restoring? I should have said that! :-) Also, see the OP's requirements `checking jobs, slowness, blocking and general overhead`.

Comment: @bwilliamson do you want them to fix anything if it is broken, or just record it and tell you in the morning? If you don't want them to fix it get some monitoring tools.

Comment: @JamesJenkins We are using Redgate for our monitoring, but ideally they would have the ability to resolve issues that may arise overnight when the onshore DBAs are sleeping.  Rerunning jobs, check and resolve blocking, expand data files and other things that do not require reviewing data.

Comment: It's a bit hard for the prison guards to keep the prisoners in check if they don't at least have riot gear! :-)

Comment: @bwilliamson I am DBA for hundreds of databases, that only honor keeps me from looking at the data of. I don't need to see it, so I don't look.  If you can not trust someone to respect your data, you probably should not be trusting them to manage your database servers.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I appreciate that.  It's not a matter of trust, but a matter of regulatory and contractual obligations.  We need our offshore team to support the instances, but they are not allowed to see the data.  Think of it as a government contract.

Comment: @bwilliamson I think that other then encrypting the data at rest (significant change) the owner of the data needs 24/7 onshore DBAs. If that is not you, you might be losing the contract.

Answer (score 0):

> What security needs to be added to give them effective control over the servers as DBAs

Seems the login required to be part of `sysadmin` as some of essential system stored procedures and most of `DBCC` commands are only accessible by `sysadmin` role member, and  it's impossible to block the access for a login that is part of `sysadmin` role. You would may think of `CONTROL SERVER` and some additional Grant/Deny on top of it without having login added into `sysadmin` fixed role. [This is what can happen in that case](http://andreas-wolter.com/en/control-server-vs-sysadmin-sa/)

I believe, it's good idea to implement [alerts](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5493/automated-wmi-alerts-for-sql-server-login-property-changes/) (that can notify via e-mail) and [audits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) on certain events rather than looking to block an **Ultimate User** at Database server